# Prove that if $U$ is a linear operator on $V$, then $UT=TU$ if and only if $U=g(T)$ for some $g(T)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a vector space $V$, and suppose that $V$ is a $T-$cycle subspace of itself. Prove that if $U$ is a linear operator on $V$, then $UT=TU$ if and only if $U=g(T)$ for some polynomial $g(t)$.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$ Suppose that $U: V \to V$ is a linear operator, $U=g(T)$ for some $g(T)$ and $V$ is generated by $v$, then the set $$\beta=\{v,T(v),T^{2}(v),...T^{k}(v)\}$$ where $\dim(V)=k$ is a basis for $V$, we need to prove that $UT=TU$, but $T(T^{k})=(T^{k})T=T^{k+1}$ and $T$ is linear, so $UT=TU$.

$\textbf{My final attempt:}$ We need to prove that if $U$ is a linear operator on $V$, then $UT=TU$ if and only if $U=g(T)$ for some polynomial $g(t)$.

$(\Longleftarrow)$ If $U=g(T)$ for some polynomial $g(t)$, so $$UT=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}T^{k}\right)T=T\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}T^{k}\right)=TU$$since $$T(T^k)=(T^k)T=T^{k+1}$$ and $T$ is a linear transformation, so $TU=UT$.

$(\implies)$ Suppose $V$ is generated by $v \in V$, then the set $$\beta=\{v,T(v),...,T^{k-1}\}$$ is a basis. So the vector $U(v)$ could be written as  linear combination of basis $\beta$. So $U(v)=g(T)(v)$ for some polynomial $g(t)$. If $UT=TU$, we want to prove that $U=g(T)(v)$ for that we can prove $\forall \hat{v} \in \beta: U(\hat{v})=g(T)(\hat{v})$. Indeed $$U(T^{n}(v))=T^{n}(U(v))=T^{n}g(T)(v)=g(T)(T^{n}(v)), \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Finally, I proved that if $U$ is a linear operator on $V$, then $UT=TU$ if and only if $U=g(T)$ for some polynomial $g(t)$.$\Box$

Comment: This is a proof of only one direction of the "if and only if"; you still need to prove that if $UT=TU$ then $U=g(T)$ for some $g$. Indeed, this is the direction (as it turns out) that requires the assumption that $V$ is $T$-cyclic; the direction that you proved works regardless of whether $V$ is $T$-cyclic.

Comment: Any suggestions for the second conditional?

Comment: I'm guessing you'll want to use the fact that $U$ and $T$ can be simultaneously diagonalized.

Comment: Check once I think $\beta$ should end with $T^{k-1}(v)$ otherwise $\beta$ is a $k+1$ element set.

Comment: thank you! I correct

Comment: Actually, you've given no guarantee that the space be finite dimensional. It's certainly possible for $V$ to be the free space on $\mathbb{N}$ and for $T$ to send the $i$th standard basis vector to the $i+1$th.

Comment: I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the set $S = \{U : UT = TU\}$ is closed under scalar multiplication, addition, and multiplication by $T$; further, note that it contains the identity matrix. Thus, $S$ contains all $g(T)$.

Now suppose we have $U \in S$. Take $v$ such that $V$ is spanned by $\{T^n v : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Then we can write every $x \in V$ as $g(T) v$ for some $v$. In particular, take $g$ such that $g(T) v = U v$. It can be shown by induction that for all $n$, $g(T) T^n v = U T^n v$ (also using the fact that $g(T) \in S$). Since $g(T)$ and $U$ agree on a set which spans $V$, they are equal.